# Golang: how can I convert a float64 currency representation to the lowest denomination? (multiplying by 100 doesn't work for all currencies)

Tags: go, floating-point, type-conversion, decimal, currency

I'm dealing with a float64 representation of money. For example, 2.9 for usd represents $2.90, so if I need to convert this to the lowest denomination for the currency, I just multiple by 100 (2.9*100= 290 cents).

This works with most major currencies. However, in Japan, for example, the float64 representation will not have a decimal because Yen is already the lowest representation. If I get float64(290) Yen, multiplying by 100 would give an excess number of Yen if I'm trying to obtain the lowest denomination - it should stay as is.

What's the best way to handle this besides special casing when to multiply by 100 for certain currencies?

EDIT: the two pieces of information I have are the float representation and the ISO currency code.

Comment: I feel like this is a more conceptual question, but I'd probably use a switch statement, a map, and/or a struct that defines currency name, and minimum denomination

Comment: I'm not sure how this is possible without metadata. If all you have is the float the only difference between values would be that Yen always have ".00". But you can't just assume if it has ".00" that value isn't needed. You could pass around an integer to track the difference between the float and the int value, but I don't think there's a way to handle this without metadata of some kind.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I also have the currency code. I guess I was hoping that this was a common enough situation that there was some native support for it, or a library that handles it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use floating-point numbers for money. Floating-point numbers are an approximation. `float64` (the set of all IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point numbers) conforms to the IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754).

Wikipedia: [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

---

Use the ISO 4217 standard to determine the minor currency unit exponent. It is 2 (10² = 100) for most currencies and 0 (10⁰ = 1) for the Japanese Yen (JPY).

Wikipedia: [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)

[Current currency & funds code list](https://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no choice in working with the floating point number to represent the amount, it's how it's sent from another system.

Comment: Ah yes the minor currency unit exponent is exactly what I need. I'm having trouble figuring out how to programmatically retrieve it in Golang though...do I really need to just create my own table? Would prefer to stick with native libraries if possible.